# Stored procedure which count records between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to count records with status 0 between two dates in SQL server 2008 
have my procedure but it is not right trows error.

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_SerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates, Line 6
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.*

Procedure looks like

```
CREATE procedure sp_SerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates
@date1 date,
@date2 date
as 
select COUNT ( Pickuphispanic ) from  pickup
where  Pickuphispanic = 1 and pickupdate like between @date1+ '%' and @date1 +'%'
```

was trying search solution in internet but no success.
Any Ideas how to wright it correct?
also i have  select statment which works perfectly

```
select COUNT ( Pickuphispanic ) from  pickup
where  Pickuphispanic = 1 and pickup.pickupdate between '2006-07-01' and '2010-12-31'
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@date1` and `@date2` parameters are of datatype `DATE` and as such you cannot append a `%` to those values (the `%` can **only** be used for string-based datatypes when using the `LIKE` operator; also: you **cannot** apply `LIKE` to a search using `DATE` values).

Use this instead:

```
CREATE procedure procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates
   @date1 date,
   @date2 date
AS
   SELECT COUNT (Pickuphispanic) 
   FROM dbo.pickup
   WHERE Pickuphispanic = 1 
     AND pickupdate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

To call this, use this syntax:

```
EXEC procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates '2006-07-01', '2010-12-31'
```

(no braces, no parenthesis - just specify the two dates), or:

```
EXEC procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates @date1 = '2006-07-01', @date2 = '2010-12-31'
```

Comment: when I call funktion {procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates ('2006-07-01','2010-12-31')} it throw error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2006-07-01'.

Comment: Are you **SURE** you're on SQL Server **2008** ?? Sounds like you might be connecting to an older engine that doesn't support `DATE` yet. What does `SELECT @@Version` give you as result?

Comment: if i do select without procedure it gives me answer 93. With procedure it trows error

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: see my updated response - you're style of calling the stored proc is wrong - it's not a C# method call - you don't need any parenthesis!

Comment: Thank You! but from C# side calling this procedure will be the same? because i need give this procedures to my web coder and he kind of new with it.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: your web coder will need to call this as he calls any stored procedure.... that's a whole different story! :) and it heavily depends on **HOW** he interfaces with the SQL Server database in the first place - raw ADO.NET? Entity Framework? NHibernate? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to search between 2 dates, your stored procedure must look like this:

```
pickupdate between @date1 and @date2
```

YOU DON'T HAVE TO USE THE LIKE FUNCTION

Comment: IF YOU WANT THE COUNT(Pickuphispanic) = 1 THEN IN YOUR STORE PROC YOU MUST USE HAVING COUNT(Pickuphispanic) = 1 INSTEAD OF THE WHERE CLAUSE.

Comment: it work right now but when i call it it trows error sp_SerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates ('2006-07-01','2010-12-31') error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2006-07-01'.

Answer (score 1):

**Like** cannot be nested on **Between** Function.

Try this:

```
CREATE procedure sp_SerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates
@date1 date,
@date2 date
as 
select COUNT ( Pickuphispanic ) from  pickup
where  Pickuphispanic = 1 and CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), pickupdate , 126) like  @date1 + '%' and @date1 + '%'
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Modify the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT ( Pickuphispanic_ID ) from  pickup
where  Pickuphispanic = 1 and pickupdate between @date1 AND @date2
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT ( Pickuphispanic_ID ) from  pickup
where  Pickuphispanic = 1 and pickupdate> @date1 AND pickupdate<@date2
```

Comment: it work but how to call procedure? if iam using procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates ('2006-07-01','2010-12-31') it gives error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2006'.

Comment: YOU MUST EXECUTE IT:
EXEC procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates ('2006-07-01','2010-12-31')

Comment: Yes, call it from your Web Program or any where else, use 'EXEC'

Comment: IF IT DOESN'T LIKE DATE TRY CONVERTING IT TO VARCHAR MAYBE THAT WILL HELP

Answer (score 0):

Like cannot be nested on Between Function.

if you want to use like then it should be like this

```
CREATE procedure sp_SerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates
@date1 date,
@date2 date
as 
select COUNT ( Pickuphispanic ) from  pickup
where  Pickuphispanic = 1 and (CONVERT(VARCHAR, pickupdate ,106) like  CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date1,106) + '%' or CONVERT(VARCHAR, pickupdate ,106) like   CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date2,106) + '%')
```

and you want to use between then it should be like this

```
CREATE procedure procSerchPickupHispanicBetweenDates
   @date1 date,
   @date2 date
AS
   SELECT COUNT (Pickuphispanic) 
   FROM dbo.pickup
   WHERE Pickuphispanic = 1 
     AND Convert(date,pickupdate) BETWEEN Convert(date,@date1) AND Convert(date,@date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

FilterDate between ISNULL(CONVERT(DATE,@FromDate),'2000-01-01') and 
ISNULL(CONVERT(DATE,@ToDate),'3000-01-01'))

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer, It will help other users in understanding the logic easily.